# Undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass, but the value is saved to the database anyway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out where this error is coming from... trying to give users the option to change some details in my Rails 5 app. The code is working, which is the most frustrating part. It's working, it updates the database, but it also throws a "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" error.

This is in my view:

```
<%= form_for @setting, url: {action: "new"} do |f| %> 
  <p>Site Name: <%= f.text_field :site_name %></p>
  <p>City Name: <%= f.text_field :location %></p>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the "new" action in the controller, same code in "update" as well:

```
def new
    @settings = Setting.first
    @settings.site_name = params[:setting][:site_name]
    @settings.location = params[:setting][:location]
    @settings.save
    redirect_to admin_url
  end
```

and the update controller:

```
def update
    @settings = Setting.first
    @settings.site_name = params[:setting][:site_name]
    @settings.location = params[:setting][:location]
    @settings.save
    redirect_to admin_url
end
```

My database has a Settings table with "site_name" and "location" as two columns.

Here's the full error:

```
NoMethodError in AdminController#new
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #29):

   27 @settings = Setting.first
   28
   29 @settings.site_name = params[:setting][:site_name]
   30 @settings.location = params[:setting][:location]
   31 @settings.save
```

Anything I enter in both of the forms gets added to the database regardless of the error so it seems like the code is working right, but it's still throwing an error. What am I missing?

Comment: Hello, could you also post your update method?

Comment: On which line it is throwing error?

Comment: Yeah, a full trace of the error will be helpful

Comment: your form submission works fine, debug your admin_url controller .something is crashing there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the individual settings that I was saving and just let the form work its magic, this is my 'new' method that is working without errors.

```
def new
    @settings = Setting.first
    respond_to do |format|
      if @settings.save
        format.html { redirect_to admin_url, notice: 'Setting was successfully changed.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @settings }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @settings.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Still not sure why there was an error in the first place but as long as it's working, I'm happy.